# android - how to stop startup applications

Tags: android

How I can programmatically find the list of applications that starts on device startup.
Is there any way to programmatically reset applications property to prevent run on startup .?

Thanks

Comment: Have a market search for `Autorun Manager`. http://androidforums.com/application-reviews/99157-autorun-killer-great-program.html This question might be better off in http://android.stackexchange.com though.

Answer (score 1):

yep, check my app [Autorun Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rs.autorun) in basic mode it displays all the startup applications and you can set the app to kill them right after they start, in advanced mode it lists all the system wide intent receivers and you can disable and enable whatever you want (this is for advanced and rooted users)

if you want to do that programmatically you need to list applications subscribed to BOOT_FINISHED android intent

Answer (score 1):

There is also this App: [Gemini App Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.seasmind.android.gmappmgr)

This gives a wide range of options, under Expert Mode, regarding Self and Auto Start, and is Free from Market.

You could also Freeze App with Paid version of [Titannium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro)

Sorry, does not answer the programmatically question directly, but gives options to prevent Apps from Auto/Self Starting